# How do I send SMTP mail from a Azure website?

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, smtp, gmail

I'm using the smtpclient class to send email from my asp.net website hosted on Azure in the 'shared' setup.  Everywhere it says that port 25, and ALL ports are open on the Azure servers.  My code works from my onw pc, but when published on Azure, it breaks.  I am using gmail port 587 secure smpt and I get the error  System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Any ways to get around this?  (Without installing a vm with Exchange on it, like ocme on, it's a simple email message).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because of these two possible reasons:

1. You are using the SMTPClient of Gmail and you are passing the EmailId of some other website like Yahoo/Hotmail etc.
2. EmailId you are using is not authenticated, you need to provide your mobile number to authenticate your Email Id.

If you are using Yahoo/Hotmail then you can refer to this article which I had created on http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/send-bulk-email-from-yahoo-and-hotmail-using-Asp-Net/